# Wordpress Theme-My-Login plugin profile page drop down will not save change to "Language"

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, profile

I am using Theme-My-Login for wordpress.
I am using user_phone field to save language preference in register-form.php

```
<?php
/*
If you would like to edit this file, copy it to your current theme's directory and edit it there.
Theme My Login will always look in your theme's directory first, before using this default template.
*/
?>
<div class="tml tml-register" id="theme-my-login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
    <?php $template->the_errors(); ?>
    <form name="registerform" id="registerform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'register', 'login_post' ); ?>" method="post">
        <?php if ( 'email' != $theme_my_login->get_option( 'login_type' ) ) : ?>
        <p class="tml-user-login-wrap">
            <label for="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Username', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_login' ); ?>" size="20" />
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <p class="tml-user-email-wrap">
            <label for="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'E-mail', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_email' ); ?>" size="20" />
        </p>
<p>
    <label for="first_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'First name', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'first_name' ); ?>" size="20" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'last_name' ); ?>" size="20" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="user_phone<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e('Preferred Language'); ?></label>
<select name="user_phone" id="user_phone<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
        <option value="English" <?php selected( $template->the_posted_value( 'user_phone' ), 'english' ); ?>>English</option>
    <option value="French" <?php selected( $template->the_posted_value( 'user_phone' ), 'french' ); ?>>French</option>
</select>
</p>

        <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

        <p class="tml-registration-confirmation" id="reg_passmail<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'tml_register_passmail_template_message', __( 'Registration confirmation will be e-mailed to you.', 'theme-my-login' ) ); ?></p>

        <p class="tml-submit-wrap">
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $template->the_redirect_url( 'register' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php $template->the_action_links( array( 'register' => false ) ); ?>
</div>
```

Following part is the language part in above code

```
<p>
<label for="user_phone<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e('Preferred Language'); ?></label>
<select name="user_phone" id="user_phone<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
        <option value="English" <?php selected( $template->the_posted_value( 'user_phone' ), 'english' ); ?>>English</option>
    <option value="French" <?php selected( $template->the_posted_value( 'user_phone' ), 'french' ); ?>>French</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Following code is where I want to call the language in Profile page and allow user to change language preference to either English or French.
I am able to call the language with below code but It's txt field and it does not save any change. How do I go about change it to drop down and save the new selection?

```
<?php
/*
If you would like to edit this file, copy it to your current theme's directory and edit it there.
Theme My Login will always look in your theme's directory first, before using this default template.
*/
?>
<div class="tml tml-profile" id="theme-my-login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
    <?php $template->the_action_template_message( 'profile' ); ?>
    <?php $template->the_errors(); ?>
    <form id="your-profile" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'profile', 'login_post' ); ?>" method="post">
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user_' . $current_user->ID ); ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="from" value="profile" />
        <input type="hidden" name="checkuser_id" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>" />

        <?php do_action( 'profile_personal_options', $profileuser ); ?>

        <h3><?php _e( 'Name', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></h3>

        <table class="tml-form-table">
        <tr class="tml-user-login-wrap">
            <th><label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'Username', 'theme-my-login' ); ?> (User ID Cannot be changed)</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->user_login ); ?>" disabled="disabled" class="regular-text" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tml-user-email-wrap">
            <th><label for="email"><?php _e( 'E-mail', 'theme-my-login' ); ?> <span class="description"><?php _e( '(required)', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></span></label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->user_email ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
            <?php
            $new_email = get_option( $current_user->ID . '_new_email' );
            if ( $new_email && $new_email['newemail'] != $current_user->user_email ) : ?>
            <div class="updated inline">
            <p><?php
                printf(
                    __( 'There is a pending change of your e-mail to %1$s. <a href="%2$s">Cancel</a>', 'theme-my-login' ),
                    '<code>' . $new_email['newemail'] . '</code>',
                    esc_url( self_admin_url( 'profile.php?dismiss=' . $current_user->ID . '_new_email' ) )
            ); ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tml-first-name-wrap">
            <th><label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->first_name ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tml-last-name-wrap">
            <th><label for="last_name"><?php _e( 'Last Name', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->last_name ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tml-last-name-wrap">

            <th><label for="language"><label for="user_phone<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e('Preferred Language'); ?></label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="user_phone" id="user_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->user_phone ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->nickname ); ?>" class="regular-text" />

        <?php
            foreach ( wp_get_user_contact_methods() as $name => $desc ) {
        ?>
        <tr class="tml-user-contact-method-<?php echo $name; ?>-wrap">
            <th><label for="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'user_'.$name.'_label', $desc ); ?></label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $profileuser->$name ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>

        <?php
        $show_password_fields = apply_filters( 'show_password_fields', true, $profileuser );
        if ( $show_password_fields ) :
        ?>

        <tr id="password" class="user-pass1-wrap">
            <th><label for="pass1"><?php _e( 'New Password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input class="hidden" value=" " /><!-- #24364 workaround -->
                <button type="button" class="button button-secondary wp-generate-pw hide-if-no-js"><?php _e( 'Generate Password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></button>
                <div class="wp-pwd hide-if-js">
                    <span class="password-input-wrapper">
                        <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" class="regular-text" value="" autocomplete="off" data-pw="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_generate_password( 24 ) ); ?>" aria-describedby="pass-strength-result" />
                    </span>
                    <div style="display:none" id="pass-strength-result" aria-live="polite"></div>
                    <button type="button" class="button button-secondary wp-hide-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Hide password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>">
                        <span class="dashicons dashicons-hidden"></span>
                        <span class="text"><?php _e( 'Hide', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="button button-secondary wp-cancel-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Cancel password change', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>">
                        <span class="text"><?php _e( 'Cancel', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="user-pass2-wrap hide-if-js">
            <th scope="row"><label for="pass2"><?php _e( 'Repeat New Password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
            <input name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" class="regular-text" value="" autocomplete="off" />
            <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Type your new password again.', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="pw-weak">
            <th><?php _e( 'Confirm Password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></th>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pw_weak" class="pw-checkbox" />
                    <?php _e( 'Confirm use of weak password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </table>

        <?php do_action( 'show_user_profile', $profileuser ); ?>

        <p class="tml-submit-wrap">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="profile" />
            <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update Profile', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```